# Regex: number sequence matching

Tags: regex

Doing text processing in Python, trying to match `<brackets>` in the output. The inside can contain any character, but if there are numbers the brackets shall not match if there is more than 1 single digit number. For instance...

```
< 1? >
<12>
<hot 198663 , ? ... @ key \n 6>
```

...**shall↑match**, while...

```
<0 0>
<9653, 8 test 6>
<18str 500 ing 4. 3 – 6>
```

...**shall↑not**.

I have tried with something like `<(?:\d{1}|\d{2,}|[^\d])>`, but it doesn’t really do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a general pattern like `<[^>]*>` and restrict it with a `(?!(?:[^>]*\b\d\b){2})` negative lookahead:

```
r'<(?!(?:[^>]*\b\d\b){2})[^>]*>'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9RlIlU/1)

**Details**

- `<` - a `<`
- `(?!(?:[^>]*\b\d\b){2})` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if exactly 2 occurrences of the following sequence is matched immediately to the right of the current location:

  - `[^>]*` - any 0+ chars other than `>`
  - `\b\d\b` - a 1-digit "whole word"
- `[^>]*` - any 0+ chars other than `>`
- `>` - a `>`

Comment: Класс, спасибо огромное!